# Texture Stretching when using a FrameBuffer and SpriteBatch

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have been working on this for 2 days and still cant figure out what is going on. I am working on a Game Framework and i have migrated from Slick2D to LibGDX and would like to render once to a texture as to save CPU/GPU cycles and improve performance. I have created a class called `DrawSurface` and its main goal is to allow me to draw to a offscreen texture and then just draw that using LibGDXs Built in Image class.

```
public final class DrawSurface {

    public static interface DrawCall{
        void draw(SpriteBatch b, int width, int height);
    }

    public static Texture offscreenDraw(DrawCall c, int canvasWidth, int canvasHeight){
        FrameBuffer fbo = new FrameBuffer(Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888,(canvasWidth),(canvasHeight),true);
        SpriteBatch batch = new SpriteBatch();
                batch.setProjectionMatrix(new Matrix4().setToOrtho2D(0,0,fbo.getWidth(),fbo.getHeight()));
        fbo.begin();
        batch.begin();
        c.draw(batch,fbo.getWidth(),fbo.getHeight());
        batch.end();
        Pixmap map = ScreenUtils.getFrameBufferPixmap(0,0,fbo.getWidth(),fbo.getHeight());
        fbo.end();
        Texture t = new Texture(map);
        map.dispose();
        return t;
    }

}
```

Which Gives me This Result When Drawing Images:
[image: Glitchy Rendering]

The "DrawCall" that is used to get this image is:

```
 Texture t = DrawSurface.offscreenDraw(new DrawSurface.DrawCall() {
            @Override
            public void draw(SpriteBatch b, int w, int h) {
                Image img = new Image(0x0000FF,w,h);
                img.setLocation(0,0);
                img.draw(b);
                for(int i = 0; i < w; i += 64){
                    for(int j = 0; j < h; j += 64){
                        Blocks.GRASS_BLOCK.setLocation(i,j);
                        Blocks.GRASS_BLOCK.draw(b);
                    }
                }
            }
        },512,512);
```

The Image should Render as a blue Square 512x512 pixels in size, with small "Grass" block images that should also be square. Sized 16x16. Unfortunately i get a warped result, and i do not understand why. As the Large White thing (a software JoyStick i created) is not stretched while the "DrawsSurface" is. If you would like a look at my camera code:

```
        // Constructor Above.
        this.gameWidth = gameWidth;
        this.gameHeight = gameHeight;
        this.camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        FlatPixelGame.gameCamera = this.camera;
        this.viewport = new StretchViewport(gameWidth,gameHeight,camera);
        this.viewport.apply();
        LogBot.log("Game Instance Created Size [%s,%s]",gameWidth,gameHeight);
        InputManager.getInstance().addListener(this);

        this.camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth / 2, camera.viewportHeight / 2, 0);
```

Any Help Would Be Appreciated, i have scoured Forums, StackOverflow and LibGDX Documentation and still cannot seem to fix this issue.

Again, Thank you in Advance :)

Comment: To note after some work, it seems to be an issue with the `Pixmap` class. I can draw and scale images as normal, but images created from Pixmaps, cause warping when drawn in this buffer.

Answer (score 0):

After a little work under the hood with LibGDX source code from BadLogic, as well as reading bug threads it seems there is an issue when converting a `PixMap` to a texture. Rendering a image derived from a file works fine, but generated images that come from a `Pixmap` can show warping due to the off-screen view-port not being the same as the current rendering view-port.

A quick way around this is using `TextureRegion`s and Sprites.

```
public static Image offscreenDraw(DrawCall c, int canvasWidth, int canvasHeight){
        FrameBuffer fbo = new FrameBuffer(Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888,canvasWidth,canvasHeight,true);
        SpriteBatch batch = new SpriteBatch();
        Matrix4 matrix = new Matrix4();
        matrix.setToOrtho2D(0, 0, canvasWidth,canvasHeight);
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(matrix);
        fbo.begin();
        batch.begin();
        c.draw(batch,canvasWidth,canvasHeight);
        batch.end();

        Texture t = fbo.getColorBufferTexture();
        t.setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Nearest, Texture.TextureFilter.Nearest);
        if(!t.getTextureData().isPrepared()){
            t.getTextureData().prepare();
        }
        fbo.end();

        TextureRegion r = new TextureRegion(t,0,0,canvasWidth,canvasHeight);
        return new Image(new com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Image(new Sprite(r)));
    }
```